# preg_replace not working my fault?

Tags: php, preg-replace

On my forum when an image is uploaded it will gain the follow html:

```
<a target="_blank" href="attachment.php?aid=1" rel="nofollow">zebra.bmp</a>
```

In order to use a plugin I have installed, I need to match those kind of html and change them to:

```
<a href="attachment.php?aid=1" rel="fancyzoom">zebra.bmp</a>
```

On the plugin it already does some conversion, example:

```
$page=preg_replace('/\<a rel="nofollow" href="attachment.php\?aid=([0-9]+)" target="_blank"\>\<img/Usi','<a href="attachment.php?aid=$1" rel="fancyzoom"><img',$page);
```

Now I am trying to catch the html I posted in the begin of my question

```
$page=preg_replace('/\<a target="_blank" href="attachment.php\?aid=([0-9]+)" rel="nofollow"\>([a-zA-Z0-9_- ]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|tif|tiff)\<\/a\>/Usi','<a href="attachment.php?aid=$1" rel="fancyzoom">$2.$3</a>',$page);
```

But the above does not seem to work is it because of the OR parenthesis ?
Is there a way to make such replace where I just want the files ending with the above image extensions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to escape the minus:

```
$page=preg_replace('/\<a target="_blank" href="attachment.php\?aid=([0-9]+)" rel="nofollow"\>([a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|tif|tiff)\<\/a\>',$page);
```

Also see my [demo](http://ideone.com/y5NYS).

=== UPDATE ===

```
$page=preg_replace('/\<a.*?href="attachment.php\?aid=([0-9]+)".*?\>([a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|tif|tiff)\<\/a\>/Usi','<a href="attachment.php?aid=$1" rel="fancyzoom">$2.$3</a>',$page);
```

My new [demo](http://ideone.com/w34sg).

Comment: thanks just tried it but doesnt seem to work, here an example: http://ideone.com/kpexa

Comment: Sure, the attributes changes the positions. I will update my regex, moment please.

Comment: WOW I just noticed it now I was using Fire Bug to inspect the element and firebug changes the `target` position with the `rel` I just checked the html and in there it doesnt LOL silly mistake. Thanks for pointing that out as well.

Answer (score 0):

would this suffice?

`\<a target="_blank" href="attachment.php\?aid=([0-9]+)" rel="nofollow"\>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|tif|tiff)\<\/a\>`

the + was the problem in this syntax

Comment: why the + is the problem ? as far as I know the more represents more of that was defined in the `[]` so it should be fine